# pthread_create() losing const char * data in struct argument

Tags: c

I'm having a bit of a strange issue that seems to be related to pthread_create.

I have a struct that contains const char * variables:

```
typedef struct Notification {
    const char *summary;
    const char *body;
} Notification;
```

It might be worth noting that data is assigned to these variables using `g_variant_get_string(content, NULL);`, which is of type `const gchar *`, but to my knowledge that should not affect this issue.

The problem seems to come when using this struct in a pthread.

```
const gchar *summary = NULL;
const gchar *body = NULL;

summary = g_variant_get_string(content, NULL);
body = g_variant_get_string(content, NULL);

Notification *n = malloc(sizeof(Notification));
assert(n != NULL);
n->summary = summary;
n->body = body;

pthread_create(&split_notification, NULL, &run, (void *)n));
```

Where run is simply:

```
void *
run(void *arg)
{
    Notification *n = (Notification *)arg;
    printf("summary: %s\n", n->summary);
    printf("body: %s\n", n->body);

    return NULL;
}
```

Where it produces garbage, such as:

```
summary: 0[
body: /
```

I have tried casting the same struct to void and back, and it produces the desired result.  What is happening?

Comment: Deos this `n->summary = summary;` compile without warning?

Comment: "*having a bit of a strange issue*" which is to be described exactly how?

Comment: *"which is of type const gchar *, but to my knowledge that should not affect this issue."* maybe, maybe not.. Why not change the `struct` to contain `const gchar *`s and be sure about it?

Comment: yes, `n->summary = summary` compiles without warning with gcc.  I have also tried casting it to `const char *` beforehand.

Comment: You need to describe the exact problem you are having, not just tell us " a strange issue"  You also need to figure out the lifetime of your variables. `n->summary ` points to what `g_variant_get_string(content, NULL);` returns, the question is then what is the lifetime of the `content` variable ? Can it be destroyed by the time your thread tries to access it ?

Comment: Sorry that I accidentally posted this early.  If you haven't read the edited version please do so.

Comment: Thank you nos, I feel like an idiot.  I was freeing `content`.

Comment: Have you tried calling `run((void*)n)` directly and studying the result? So this way you can deduce a pthread issue?